# how can i add different numbers in one variable?

Tags: java

```
int courses = input.nextInt();

for (int i = 1; i <= coses; i++) {

    System.out.println("Course No" + i);

    System.out.println("Enter course title : ");

    String title = input.next();

    System.out.println("Enter course grade : ");

    String grade = input.next();

    System.out.println("Enter course unit : ");

    int unit = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("");

}
```

from the code above, i want to add all the values store in the "int unit" variable, into the number of times specified by the inputter.

Comment: So you want to get input multiple times and sum the inputs?

Comment: use `method local` or `class variable` (static or non-static) to sum the input units.

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
int courses = input.nextInt();
        int unit =0;

    for(int i = 1;i<= courses ;i++)
    {

        System.out.println("Course No" + i);

        System.out.println("Enter course title : ");

        String title = input.next();

        System.out.println("Enter course grade : ");

        String grade = input.next();

        System.out.println("Enter course unit : ");

        unit = unit + input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("");

    }
```

Comment: Maybe some comments can help the OP

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify, you want to take all the keyboard inputs and store them all within a variable called "int unit"?

Or you do you want to do some algebra to get a number (like a class average)  and store that number in an variable?

Or do you want separate variables for each thing they would input that would store it for every iteration of the for loop? 
(So like a 'courseNumber',  'courseTitle', 'courseGrade',  'courseUnit' variables)

If you can give me a little more clarification I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

`Non-static` way. Initialized a variable before the `for` loop as `int unit = 0;`.

```
int courses = input.nextInt();
int unit = 0;

for (int i = 1; i <= courses ; i++) {
   System.out.println("Course No" + i);       
   unit += input.nextInt();
}

System.out.println(unit);
```

Or you can implement `static` variable as `static int unit;`.

```
class Sum{
  static int unit;
  public static void main (String[] args){

     Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
     int courses = input.nextInt();

     for (int i = 1; i <= courses ; i++) {
       System.out.println("Course No" + i);       
       unit += input.nextInt();
     }

     System.out.println(unit);
  }
}
```

To view the out-put add `System.out.println(unit);` outside of the `for` loop.

`unit += input.nextInt();` will add all unit results. This is same as `unit = unit + input.nextInt();`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class add{
    static int unit;
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int courses = input.nextInt();

        for (int i = 1; i <= courses; i++) {

            System.out.println("Course No" + i);
            System.out.println("Enter course title : ");
            String title = input.next();

            System.out.println("Enter course grade : ");
            String grade = input.next();

            System.out.println("Enter course unit : ");
            unit = unit + input.nextInt();

            System.out.println("");

        }
        System.out.println("Unit:" + unit);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try some thing like this

```
  int unit = unit + input.nextInt();
```

It will be wise to bring all the variable declarations outside the for loop..